# Convolution of step function and exponential decay

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, convolution

I'm trying to apply the following formula to my data:

[image: M(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau&space;)G(t-\tau)d\tau=\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau&space;)[A\frac{\lambda&space;_{bi}}{\lambda&space;_{bi}-\lambda&space;_{pb}}(e^{-\lambda&space;_{pb}(t-\tau)}-e^{-\lambda&space;_{bi}(t-\tau)})+Be^{-\lambda&space;_{bi}(t-\tau)}]d\tau]

where A = 0.3, B=1, lambda_pb = 0.000431062, lambda_bi = 0.000580525.

For time t, I have:

```
t=np.array([0, 900, 1800, 2700, 3600, 4500, 5400, 6300, 7200, 8100])
```

and f(t):

```
f=np.array([ 0., 0., 0.00555556, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

For G(t):

```
G=np.array([ 1., 0.69255058,  0.47822256,  0.32940846, 0.22642738,  0.15536312,  0.10643991,  0.07282715,  0.04977304,  0.03398402])
```

Then I'm convolving G(t) and f(t) using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import convolve
convolution=np.convolve(f, G)[:len(t)]*(t[1]-t[0])
```

I obtain the following plot : [image]
For t < tau, I obtain the curve in red. However, this is not correct, since for t < tau, G(t-tau)=0 (causality principle). Hence, I would like to obtain the black curve (vertical increase at t=tau). Can anyone tell me how to improve my code to do that and only account for the response function G(t-tau) for t>tau? Maybe using a step function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a problem about plot?

I know nothing about your formula, but the convolution result looks good to me. However, with data [0, 0, 0.00555556...], `plt.plot` will plot a curve like that. `plt.step` may solve this problem

```
plt.step(t[:3], convolution[:3], where='post', color='r')
plt.plot(t[2:], convolution[2:], color='r')
```

or, if you could, resampling t could also alleviate it

```
def G(t):
    term1 = A * lambda_bi / (lambda_bi - lambda_pb) 
    term2 = np.exp(-lambda_pb * t) - np.exp(-lambda_bi * t)
    term3 = B * np.exp(-lambda_bi * t)
    return term1 * term2 + term3

t = np.linspace(0, 8100, 811)

f = np.zeros(t.shape)
f[t==1800] = 0.00555556

g = G(t)

conv = np.convolve(f, g)[:len(t)]*(t[1]-t[0])
plt.plot(conv)
```